# How do I do multiple CASE WHEN conditions using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What I'm trying to do is use more than one CASE WHEN condition for the same column.

Here is my code for the query:

```
   SELECT   Url='',
            p.ArtNo,
            p.[Description],
            p.Specification,
            CASE 
            WHEN 1 = 1 or 1 = 1 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
            END as Qty,
            p.NetPrice,
            [Status] = 0
      FROM  Product p (NOLOCK)
```

However, what I want to do is use more then one WHEN for the same column "qty".

As in the following code:

```
IF
// CODE
ELSE IF
// CODE
ELSE IF
// CODE
ELSE
// CODE
```

Comment: Is there something about `case when <condition> then <vaue> when <condition> then <value> . . .  end` that isn't working?

Comment: As @GordonLinoff was saying, you can have more than one `WHEN`.

Comment: It's exactly as you say. I had put a parenthesis in the wrong place. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 557, accepted):

There are [three formats of case expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql). You can do `CASE` with many `WHEN` as;

```
CASE  WHEN Col1 = 1 OR Col3 = 1  THEN 1 
      WHEN Col1 = 2 THEN 2
      ...
      ELSE 0 END as Qty
```

*Or* a Simple `CASE` expression

```
CASE Col1 WHEN 1 THEN 11 WHEN 2 THEN 21 ELSE 13 END
```

*Or* `CASE` *within* `CASE` as;

```
CASE  WHEN Col1 < 2 THEN  
                    CASE Col2 WHEN 'X' THEN 10 ELSE 11 END
      WHEN Col1 = 2 THEN 2
      ...
      ELSE 0 END as Qty
```

Comment: THERE ARE TWO.  *Lists three* :D

Comment: Is the inner case being validated if the outter case doesn't return true?

Comment: @d8aninja They only listed 2. The third is a combination of the first two, with the outer case being the first type and the inner case being the second type.

Answer (score 23):

Just use this one, You have to use more when they are classes.

```
SELECT   Url='',
         p.ArtNo,
         p.[Description],
         p.Specification,
         CASE 
         WHEN 1 = 1 or 1 = 1 
            THEN 1 
         WHEN 2 = 2
             THEN 2
         WHEN 3 = 3
              THEN 3
          ELSE 0 
        END as Qty,
        p.NetPrice,
        [Status] = 0
  FROM  Product p (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use below example of case when with multiple conditions.

```
SELECT
  id,stud_name,
  CASE
    WHEN marks <= 40 THEN 'Bad'
    WHEN (marks >= 40 AND
      marks <= 100) THEN 'good'
    ELSE 'best'
  END AS Grade
FROM Result
```

Answer (score 5):

Something Like this, Two Conditions Two Columns

```
SELECT ITEMSREQ.ITEM AS ITEM,
       ITEMSREQ.CANTIDAD AS CANTIDAD,
       (CASE  WHEN ITEMSREQ.ITEMAPROBADO=1 THEN 'APROBADO'
              WHEN ITEMSREQ.ITEMAPROBADO=0 THEN 'NO APROBADO'
        END) AS ITEMS,
        (CASE 
              WHEN ITEMSREQ.ITEMAPROBADO = 0 
              THEN CASE WHEN REQUISICIONES.RECIBIDA IS NULL  THEN 'ITEM NO APROBADO PARA ENTREGA' END
              WHEN ITEMSREQ.ITEMAPROBADO = 1 
              THEN CASE WHEN REQUISICIONES.RECIBIDA IS NULL THEN 'ITEM AUN NO RECIBIDO' 
                        WHEN REQUISICIONES.RECIBIDA=1 THEN 'RECIBIDO' 
                        WHEN REQUISICIONES.RECIBIDA=0 THEN 'NO RECIBIDO' 
                       END
              END)
              AS RECIBIDA
 FROM ITEMSREQ
      INNER JOIN REQUISICIONES ON
      ITEMSREQ.CNSREQ = REQUISICIONES.CNSREQ
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be an efficient way of performing different tests on a single statement

```
select
case colour_txt 
  when 'red' then 5 
  when 'green' then 4 
  when 'orange' then 3
else 0 
end as Pass_Flag
```

this only works on equality comparisons!

Answer (score 2):

```
    case when first_condition
      then first_condition_result_true
    else
      case when second_condition 
        then second_condition_result_true
      else
          second_condition_result_false                              
      end
    end
  end as qty
```

Comment: There's no need to nest CASES expressions like this, you can have multiple WHEN clauses in a single CASE.

Comment: When the first condition is met, the rest of the conditions are ignored?

Answer (score 2):

```
case 
    when a.REASONID in ('02','03','04','05','06') then
        case b.CALSOC 
            when '1' then 'yes' 
            when '2' then 'no' 
            else 'no' 
        end
    else 'no' 
end
```

Comment: Please, format your answer and possibly add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Its just that you need multiple `WHEN` for a single case to behave it like `if.. Elseif else..`

```
       CASE WHEN 1=1       --if
       THEN
        WHEN 1=1              --else if
         THEN ... 
        WHEN ...             --else if
        THEN 
        ELSE                      --else
       ......
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get an idea from this code.

```
SELECT

(CASE
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1001' THEN 'DM'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1002' THEN 'GS'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1003' THEN 'MB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1004' THEN 'MP'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1005' THEN 'PL'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1008' THEN 'DM-27'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1011' THEN 'PB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1012' THEN 'UT-2'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1013' THEN 'JGC'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1014' THEN 'SB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1015' THEN 'IR'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1016' THEN 'UT-3'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1017' THEN 'UT-4'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1019' THEN 'KR'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1020' THEN 'SYB-SB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1021' THEN 'GR'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1022' THEN 'SYB-KP'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1026' THEN 'BNS'

  ELSE ''
END) AS OUTLET

FROM matrixcrm.Transact
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but it was dealing with dates.
Query to show all items for the last month, works great without conditions until Jan.
In order for it work correctly, needed to add a year and month variable

```
declare @yr int
declare @mth int

set @yr=(select case when month(getdate())=1 then YEAR(getdate())-1 else YEAR(getdate())end)
set @mth=(select case when month(getdate())=1 then month(getdate())+11 else month(getdate())end)
```

Now I just add the variable into condition:
...

```
(year(CreationTime)=@yr and MONTH(creationtime)=@mth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining all conditions

```
select  a.* from tbl_Company a

where  a.Company_ID NOT IN (1,2)  

AND (   
        (0 = 
            CASE WHEN (@Fromdate = '' or @Todate='')
                THEN 0 
                ELSE 1  
            END
        )      -- if 0=0 true , if 0=1 fails (filter only when the fromdate and todate is present)
                OR
        (a.Created_Date between @Fromdate and @Todate )                 
    )
```