# SQL CASE statement for if

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I've looked around and cannot find an answer to this. As far as I'm aware I'm using this correctly but I'm obviously missing something as it keeps coming back with 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE''

I'm trying to take two values, and depending on what 'word' they are return a value of 1-5. These then get multiplied together to give me a 'rating'

```
DECLARE @PR int
DECLARE @IR int
DECLARE @R int
DECLARE @ProbabilityRating varchar(max)
DECLARE @ImpactRating varchar(max)

SET @ProbabilityRating = 'High'
SET @ImpactRating = 'Medium'

CASE @ProbabilityRating
    WHEN 'Very Low' THEN @PR = 1
    WHEN 'Low' THEN @PR = 2
    WHEN 'Medium' THEN @PR = 3
    WHEN 'High' THEN @PR = 4
    WHEN 'Very High' THEN @PR = 5
END

CASE @ImpactRating
    WHEN 'Very Low' THEN @IR = 1
    WHEN 'Low' THEN @IR = 2
    WHEN 'Medium' THEN @IR = 3
    WHEN 'High' THEN @IR = 4
    WHEN 'Very High' THEN @IR = 5
END

SET @R = @IR * @PR
```

Where is this going wrong?!

Comment: This looks like T-SQL, so I am tagging it thus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're reusing that `case`, maybe it makes sense to have those values in a table ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ed90/2)):

```
create table Ratings
(
   Value int
  ,Description varchar(20)
)

insert Ratings values
 (1,'Very Low')
,(2,'Low')
,(3,'Medium')
,(4,'High')
,(5,'Very High')
```

And then assign the variables from a select...

```
select 
 @IR = r.Value
from Ratings as r
where r.[Description] = @ImpactRating

select 
 @PR = r.Value
from Ratings as r
where r.[Description] = @ProbabilityRating
```

Alternatively, you could just create a temp table ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21448)):

```
select
 d.*
into #Ratings
from (values
 ('Very Low',1)
,('Low',2)
,('Medium',3)
,('High',4)
,('Very High',5)
) d([Description], Value)

select 
 @IR = r.Value
from #Ratings as r
where r.[Description] = @ImpactRating

select 
 @PR = r.Value
from #Ratings as r
where r.[Description] = @ProbabilityRating
```

As for your syntax issue, it seems like you're confusing a sql `case` with a `switch` (from other languages) where you'd branch to execute different code. They look pretty similar, so that's understandable. They behave differently, though. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **`CASE`**
>   
> Evaluates a list of conditions **and returns one** of multiple possible result expressions.

That's to say, a case statement resolves to a value. Simply assign that value to your variable, like so:

```
set @PR = case @ProbabilityRating
    when 'Very Low' then 1
    when 'Low' then 2
    when 'Medium' then 3
    when 'High' then 4
    when 'Very High' then 5
end
```

Comment: Thanks - Used the temp table in the end

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @PR int
DECLARE @IR int
DECLARE @R int
DECLARE @ProbabilityRating varchar(max)
DECLARE @ImpactRating varchar(max)

SET @ProbabilityRating = 'High'
SET @ImpactRating = 'Medium'
set @PR=(CASE @ProbabilityRating
    WHEN 'Very Low' THEN  1
    WHEN 'Low' THEN   2
    WHEN 'Medium' THEN  3
    WHEN 'High' THEN  4
    WHEN 'Very High' THEN   5
END)
set @IR=(
CASE @ImpactRating
    WHEN 'Very Low' THEN  1
    WHEN 'Low' THEN  2
    WHEN 'Medium' THEN  3
    WHEN 'High' THEN  4
    WHEN 'Very High' THEN  5
END)

SET @R = @IR * @PR
print @r
```

Your query should be looks like this 
Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14631123/2630817

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 1):

This is a big long for a comment.

`case` is an expression inside a SQL statement that typically starts with `select`, `update`, `delete`, or `set`.  It is *not* control flow logic in the scripting language, which is called T-SQL.  `if` is control flow, but you don't need `if` in this case.  Just use:

```
SET @PR = (CASE @ProbabilityRating
             WHEN 'Very Low' THEN 1
             WHEN 'Low' THEN 2
             WHEN 'Medium' THEN 3
             WHEN 'High' THEN 4
             WHEN 'Very High' THEN 5
           END);

SET @IR = (CASE @ImpactRating
             WHEN 'Very Low' THEN 1
             WHEN 'Low' THEN 2
             WHEN 'Medium' THEN 3
             WHEN 'High' THEN 4
             WHEN 'Very High' THEN 5
           END);
```

Answer (score 0):

You either do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @ImpactRating = 'Very Low' THEN ... END AS @IR
```

Or

```
IF @ImpactRating = 'Very Low'
    BEGIN
        SET @IR = 1
    END
ELSE IF @Impactrating = 'Low'
...
```

CASE/WHEN is used in a select/update/delete query, and IF/ELSE is used in the flow. Hope this makes sense