# Checking if a value exists on a sub-query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   c.callID,
   c.time,
   c.duration,
   (case_statement) AS inquiry_type
FROM calls AS c
```

My question is on regard to build the case_statement. There is another table `call_hco` that associates `calls` and `hco` together.

I need the `case_statement` to be if `callID` has `hco = 61` on `call_hco` table then `inquiry_type` will be "Service". If `callID` has `hco = 52` or `hco = 54` or `hco = 56` then `inquiry_type` will be "Sales", otherwise `inquiry_type` will be "NULL".

It is worth mentioning that if you query on `call_hco` for a specific `callID` it can return one or more rows since the same `callID` could be associated with more than one `hco`.

Query results should look something like:

```
callID    time    duration(seconds)    inquiry_type
12        15:35         55                 Service
15        10:56         135                Sales
16        18:36         45                 NULL
18        13:00         234                Sales
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is  `c.callID` the key to call_hco? Give us the definition for call_hco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do multiple CASE WHEN conditions using SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630984/how-do-i-do-multiple-case-when-conditions-using-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I would prefer to have a CallType table. Then you can simply left join to it on hco. Then if you need to change it your query will just work and you don't have to change the hard coded case expression. Or add another column in your hco table to have the inquiry_type in there.

Comment: call_hco has call_cho_id(integer), callID(integer), hco(integer) and some non related columns like ip, timeEntered etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is worth mentioning that if you query on call_hco for a specific callID it can return one or more rows since the same callID could be associated with more than one hco.

To correctly answer this question, we need to know how you decide which 
`call_hco` record is correct. Is there a time stamp? Is the hco field a progression (so highest number always wins)? Do you want to show multiple results for that call?

Without this information we're only guessing.

That said, I'll take a guess that may be enough for you to finish on your own. Try using an APPLY operation as you would a JOIN, to limit each record from the original table to exactly one matching record from the added table:

```
SELECT 
   c.callID,
   c.time,
   c.duration,
   CASE WHEN h.hco = 61 THEN 'Service' WHEN h.hco IN (52,54,56) THEN 'Sales' ELSE NULL END AS inquiry_type
FROM calls AS c
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 hco 
        FROM call_hco 
        WHERE call_hco.callID = c.callID 
            AND call_hco.callID IN (52,54,56,61)
        ORDER BY hco DESC) h
```

Again... the `ORDER BY` here is a wild guess that probably isn't what you want, but you can use this technique to get the record you really do want.

Because you only need one field from `call_hco` you could also do this with a correlated derived table (sub query) in the select clause, and possibly abstract that to a CTE to make the query easier to understand and maintain. But I find APPLY easier to work with, and it makes it simple to also get additional fields from the related table.

You can make this even better with an `hco_type` table that might look something like this:

```
hco  type
61   Service
52   Sales
54   Sales
56   Sales
```

Then you could simplify the `CASE` expression by also joining to this new table:

```
SELECT 
   c.callID,
   c.time,
   c.duration,
   t.type
FROM calls AS c
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 hco 
        FROM call_hco 
        WHERE call_hco.callID = c.callID 
            AND call_hco.callID IN (52,54,56,61)
        ORDER BY hco DESC) h
LEFT JOIN hco_type t ON t.hco = h.hco
```

Comment: There is no rule on which call_hco record to take. I need to check if for the given callID there is a record on this table. If so then, if there is a value of 61 then I need to display the string "Service". If there is one of the following values (52,54,56) then display the string "Sales". If there is no records at all OR there are records but none of the hco values above then display "NULL". 
I prefer a case statement on the select part of the query and avoid joining on call_hco table since when I join it increase the numbers of rows returned and it is getting more complicated to filter.

Comment: What if you have both sales and service hco values? Anyway, based on that I updated the query so it may do what you need already. This APPLY query will _never_ increase the number of rows returned, but it might return inconsistent or unpredictable results if a call has both a Sales and Server hco.

Comment: This worked perfect for what I wanted. I really like the idea of call_type table you added and makes the code easier to read. Thank you.

Comment: @DoArNa I'm still curious: if a call has an hco for both 61 and 52, how do you know if it's Sales or Service?

Comment: A call can not have both values. The way it works is when a call comes in there is a process (including humans) that assign the call with an hco value which is either 61 (Service) or 52 or 54 or 56 for Sales (different types of Sales). The call can be assigned further hco values like 94 (left an appointment) or 86 (didn't leave an appointment and so on. So a call can have multiple hco values like 61 and 94 which means it is a Service call and left an appointment however it CAN NOT have 61 and let say 52 because that will mean it is a Service and Sale call on the same time.

Comment: If a call would've be possible to have both of 61 and any of the values (52,54,56) on the same time then this solution wouldn't work for me since the query selects only top 1. In my case even though the query says SELECT TOP 1, technically that is just to be on safe side but that query will never select more than one row even without the part TOP 1

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward since you've already laid out the conditions.  The only part that's easy to mess up is not putting the `ELSE null` as the last condition:

```
SELECT 
   c.callID,
   c.time,
   c.duration,
   CASE 
     WHEN h.hco = 61 THEN 'Service'
     WHEN h.hco in (52,54,56) THEN 'Sales'
     ELSE null
    END AS inquiry_type
FROM calls AS c
inner join hco_table as h
on c.callID = h.callID
```

Comment: I prefer a case statement on the select part of the query and avoid joining on call_hco table since when I join it increase the numbers of rows returned and it is getting more complicated to filter. Is that possible?

Comment: Not in a way I can think of.  As the top answer suggests there are methods to make a joined query return one row per ID, but you do need to specify which row somehow.

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't need to return any row at all. What I need is to compare if my given value (e.g. 61) is part of the results on the sub-query and if it is then display "Service" and so on for the other values....

Comment: Right, that's what this query if you specify which single hco row to check per `callID`.  You'll only get the specified fields, which do not include any of the hco fields.

Comment: Oh I see what you saying. I will give a shot to that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that callID is the key to both tables. Where call_hco has multiple rows with the same callID then there will be multiple rows in the result too:

```
SELECT 
   c.callID,
   c.time,
   c.duration,
   CAST (
       case h.hco 
         WHEN 61 THEN 'Service' 
         WHEN 52 THEN 'Sales' 
         WHEN 54 THEN 'Sales' 
         WHEN 56 THEN 'Sales' 
         ELSE NULL END AS varchar(7) 
        )
                                        AS inquiry_type
FROM calls AS c
   LEFT JOIN call_hco as h
        ON h.callID = c.callID 
           AND h.hco IN ( 61, 52, 54, 56 );
```

Edit: I have added the clause `AND h.hco IN (...)` to avoid adding rows where call_hco.hco does not match these values.

Comment: I prefer a case statement on the select part of the query and avoid joining on call_hco table since when I join it increase the numbers of rows returned and it is getting more complicated to filter.
Is that possible?

Comment: I added the extra filter on the join to avoid adding rows where not needed