# Multiple CASEs - syntax

Tags: sql

**Disclaimer:** it is probably a trivial mistake.

---

To solve the query at [this link](https://www.sqlteaching.com/#!case):

> Can you return the results with a column named sound that returns
>   "talk" for humans, "bark" for dogs, and "meow" for cats?

I need to write a `CASE` with multiple possibilities.

What is wrong with the following syntax?

```
SELECT *
CASE 
    WHEN species='human' THEN 'talk' 
    WHEN species='dog' THEN 'bark'
    WHEN species='cat' THEN 'meow'
  END AS sound
FROM friends_of_pickles
;
```

I double-checked the syntax bar reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630984/how-do-i-do-multiple-case-when-conditions-using-sql-server-2008) and it seems correct to me?

Where is the mistake?

Thank you **very** much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are missing a comma after `*`:

```
SELECT *,
       (CASE WHEN species = 'human' THEN 'talk' 
             WHEN species = 'dog' THEN 'bark'
             WHEN species = 'cat' THEN 'meow'
        END) AS sound
FROM friends_of_pickles;
```

However, some databases do not allow `*` with other columns.  So a qualified `*` is required:

```
SELECT fop.*,
       (CASE WHEN species = 'human' THEN 'talk' 
             WHEN species = 'dog' THEN 'bark'
             WHEN species = 'cat' THEN 'meow'
        END) AS sound
FROM friends_of_pickles fop;
```

To be honest, I recommend a qualifying column names (and `*`s) in general.

Comment: And the case clause can be shortened to `CASE species  WHEN 'human' THEN 'talk' WHEN 'dog' THEN 'bark' WHEN 'cat' THEN 'meow' END AS sound`.